# php laravel array excel mongodb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel, parsing

i am facing this small problem , i have this array  parsed from Excel tables. the first one is the attribute and the second one is the value , and i want to make it pretty JSON ,  on line 32 where closet is alone and 33 is empty array ( which indicated a new table so i need it in json to be as a sub like this :

```
{"name":"bla bla bla" , "date":"2017-06-20" , "status":"active" , "closet":{{"type":"PS100","number":"PST_2" ,"quant in A":"23","quant in B":"4","Mb":"100"} ,{"type":"PS200","number":"PST_2" ,"quant in A":"9","quant in B":"1","Mb":"0"},{"type":"PS300","number":"PST_3" ,"quant in A":"3","quant in B":"100","Mb":"0"},{"type":"PS400","number":"PST_4" ,"quant in A":"23","quant in B":"9","Mb":"50"}}
```

this is the array i am getting :

```
  46 => "name"
  47 => "bla bla bla"
  48 => "date"
  49 => "2017-06-20"
  50 => "status"
  51 => "active"
  52 => "closet"
  53 => []
  54 => "type"
  55 => "number"
  56 => "quant in A"
  57 => "quant in B"
  58 => "Mb"
  59 => "PS100"
  60 => "PST_2"
  61 => "23"
  62 => "4"
  63 => "100"
  64 => "PS200"
  65 => "PST_2"
  66 => "9"
  67 => "1"
  68 => "0"
  69 => "SP300"
  70 => "PST_3"
  71 => "3"
  72 => "100"
  73 => "SP400"
  74 => "PST_4"
  75 => "9"
  76 => "50"
```

my code for getting such an array :

```
    if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
        Excel::load($request->file('import_file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) {

            $result[] = $reader->toArray();
            //dump($result[0]);
            $result = array_values(array_filter($result));
            $ref =(array_values(array_filter(array_dot($result), function($value) { return $value !== null; } )));
            dump($ref);
```

pic of the table :

[image]

thanks guys

Comment: i am using laravel and maatwebsite :) code updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json_encode function

```
json_encode($my_array);
```